# Spring MVC 4 Project(InternalResourceViewResolver class not found)

Tags: spring, view, resources, internal, resolver

before giving any response, please test it yourself. because i have tried all the IDE with different spring framework version. i have tried 4.0.4 to latest 4.2. but never got the right answer. please help me and guide me. thanks in advance.

[this is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwZpi.jpg)

this is my controller class, HelloWorld

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller

public class HelloWorld {
    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public ModelAndView hello(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Hi there......");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

this is my spring configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

this is my web.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.RESTfullService.learning</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC4part8</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVC4part8 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
            programming implementation allowing you to define -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
            Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
            for web applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
            such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
            IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC4part8</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

this is index.jsp file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${msg}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class package is not the right one. It should be `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`

[Spring Java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html)